# Seleccionar los registros de 3 tablas

Tags: sql, postgresql

tengo la siguiente relacion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla sección siempre tendrá ésta información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito buscar en la tabla transformador por numero de serie, ejemplo: "358296".

Necesito seleccionar los datos del transformador segun el numero de serie que se ha ingresado, también necesito mostrar las secciones por la cual ha pasado el transformador(**tabla secciontransformador**), en la mayoria de los casos el transformador puede no haber pasado por ninguna seccion, por lo tanto se debe mostrar las secciones que no ha pasado, es decir todas las secciones de la tabla "**secciones**" que mostrar por cual seccion ya ha pasado y por cual no ha pasado.

Aqui obtengo todas las secciones sin importar que no hayan registros de secciones por transformador.

```
select * from seccion s 
left join secciontransformador st on s.idseccion=st.idseccion;
```

Aqui obtengo todos los datos del transformador sin importar que no tenga datos en la tabla **secciontransformador**

```
select * from transformador t
left join secciontransformador st on t.idtransformador=st.idtransformador 
where t.numeroserie='358296';
```

En realidad la consulta debe retornar 12 filas, 12 es la cantidad de secciones que hay registrdas en la tabla **seccion**; se repetirá los datos del transformador; y deberá mostrar los secciones por donde ha pasado el transformador y por donde no ha pasado...

Supongo que para determinar las secciones por las que no ha pasado el transformador deberá quedar alguna columna id null o algun campo null y así uno determinar que si es null es porque no ha pasado por ésa sección.

Si consideran necesario cambiar las estructuras de las tablas, podemos hacerlo. :D

Esta consulta funciona bien pero me retorna un sólo registro, ya que encuentra un sólo registro en la tabla **transformador** que coincida con el numero de serie: **358296**

```
select s.nombreseccion from secciontransformador st 
full join seccion s using(idseccion)
full join transformador t on st.idtransformador=t.idtransformador
where t.numeroserie='358296';
```

Pero necesito traer los (12) nombres de cada seccion de la tabla **sección**.

Comment: que gestor usas? por que pusiste tanto mysql como postgreSQL

Comment: Pido Disculpas.Yo uso PostgreSQL, actualizaré la preguntas con los codigos que he intentado.

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.*, tr.* from seccion s 
left join secciontransformador st on s.idseccion=st.idseccion
LEFT join( 
    select * from transformador t where t.numeroserie='358296'
) as tr on st.idtransformador=tr.idtransformador;
```

:D